# Jmeter: wrapper for jmeter obects in groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

H, I have code like this in JSR223 Assertion

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

failureMessage = "";
sampleLabel = SampleResult.getSampleLabel();

isResponseCodeCorrect("204");


def isResponseCodeCorrect(String expCode)
{
  String actualCode = prev.getResponseCode();

  if(!expCode.equals(actualCode)){

    failureMessage += "ERROR code: Expected <"+ expCode +"> but we got instead  " + actualCode + ";";           
  }
}
```

The question is possible to create the some code library in groovy or java and inject the objects form executed sampler (like public variables: ctx, vars, props, SamplerResult)?

The goal is to inject objects like SampleResult, AssertionResult (to invoke -> SampleResult.getSampleLabel()),  AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("failureMessage);
         AssertionResult.setFailure(true); ) and own functions.

Like to have the wrapper (some object) with methods to play with Assertion, saving data to CSV ... The wrapper is going to be imported to JSR223 Assertion and then I would like to call some specific methods.

The expected wrapper:

```
 @groovy.transform.MapConstructor
   class Foo {
    SampleResult results,
    AssertionResult assertionResult

    isResponseCodeCorrect(String expCode) {
        String actualCode = prev.getResponseCode();

    if(!expCode.equals(actualCode)){

        failureMessage += "ERROR code: Expected <"+ expCode +"> but we got instead  " + actualCode + ";";       
     assertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
     assertionResult.setFailure(true);   

     log.error(sampleLabel + " Error is going to be saved to the logs");
     PrintLogToFile();          
       }
    }
}
```

JSR223 Assertion:

```
import org.foo. wrapper

Foo wrapper = new Foo();
wrapper.isResponseCodeCorrect("200");
```

Or some useful things to avoid code duplication between calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile your Groovy or Java code into a [.jar file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) and drop it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Once done you will be able to access the functions available in the .jar file from any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and/or from [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy).

I can think only of one class which you need: [JMeterContext](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) an instance of which can be obtained as simple as:

```
def ctx = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext()
```

once done you will be able to access whatever you need like:

- `SampleResult` == `ctx.getPreviousResult()`
- `AssertionResult` == `ctx.getPreviousResult().getAssertionResults()`
- `vars` == `ctx.getVariables()`
- `props` == `ctx.getProperties()`
- etc.

Check out [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time/) article for more details if needed.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much. I'v investigated the information you shared. Context nice solution. But I faced with Jmeter api restrictions, is not possible to invoke the assert fail from the external class. But it's possible to get the all things from context and play with that. That's better solution to develop the utility and avoid code duplication for some cases. I have been developing my own utility wich optimize the memory consuming. Thank you again :)